# Display Review tab after other 2 tabs in product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, tabs

we are displaying `Reviews tab` above & other 2 tabs `Product secription` & `Features`  below in [Product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) , I want to display `Reviews tab` next to other 2 tabs.

[image]

**code for 2 tabs** [view.phtml]

```
<div id="tab-container">
    <div class="tabs active" onclick="changeTab(0)">Product Description</div>
    <div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(1)">Features</div>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-text active">
        INSERT FIRST TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-text">
        INSERT SECOND TAB CONTENT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

**code for Review tab** [ app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/helper/summary_short.phtml ]

```
<?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <span class="amount"><a href="#" onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href='<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>'; return false;"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></a></span>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($this->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>
    <p class="no-rating"><a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So you want, "Reviews" tab to go to the bottom next to the other 2 or the other 2 to go top the top next to "Reviews"? Do you want to have 3 tabs?

Comment: @Paul i want to display `review tab` on right side of other 2 tabs.

Comment: Check my answer below @BabyinMagento and if you don't understand something just let me know.

Comment: @Paul can you please help [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124266/display-reviews-under-tabs-in-product-view-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

[image]
If you do not understand something please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code under html code

```
<?php
    $reviewListBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/product_view_list');
    $reviewFormBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/form');

    echo $reviewListBlock->setTemplate('review/product/view/list.phtml')->toHtml();
    echo $reviewFormBlock->setTemplate('review/form.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: Add above code under html code