# Display Reviews under tabs in product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, review, tabs

We are displaying tabs in product view page as below

[image]

Under **Add Review tab** we need to provide an option to write review for customer.

we are following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193634/how-to-add-review-tab-on-product-view-page) , what i did is i added below code in `catalog.xml` file

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
    <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>tab_review_list</alias><title>Product Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>catalog/product/view/tabs/reviews.phtml</template></action>
</block>

<reference name="tab_review_list">
  <block type="review/form" name="tab_review_form" as="review_form" template="catalog/product/view/tabs/review_form.phtml" />
</reference>
```

and using  `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form'); ? >` in view.phtml file

Comment: Check this link:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193634/how-to-add-review-tab-on-product-view-page

Comment: @SachinS thanks for link,  i tried that, but didt worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `catalog.xml` ,

In `<catalog_product_view translate="label">` handler

add below

```
<reference name="review_tabbed">
   <block type="review/form" name="tab_review_form" as="review_form" template="review/form.phtml" />
</reference>
```

In

```
 <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
        ......
        ......
     </block>
```

Add below

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review" ><alias>review_tabbed</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template></action>
```

Comment: i can not able to find this line : `<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >`

Comment: can you please tell me where i need to second block of code in catalog.xml file

Comment: `<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >` will be in layout/catalog.xml of theme

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like below. Or you can create local.xml and put below code into this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout> 
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
         <reference name="product.info.additional">       
          <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
            <action method="setTemplate" ><template>catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>description_tabbed</alias><title>Product Features</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ><alias>additional_tabbed</alias><title>Additional Info</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>               

            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review" ><alias>review_tabbed</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template></action>
          </block>
         </reference>        
        <reference name="review_tabbed">
            <block type="review/form" name="tab_review_form" as="review_form" template="review/form.phtml" />
        </reference>             
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: i added code in `local.xml` but it didt added any `review tab` [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/vintage-retro-bicycle-background-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) is i need to add any code in view.phtml file? is review tab in view page is 1.9 default feature ?

Answer (score 1):

I had issues getting the review option to show up on our site also. 
 It turns out that the value for this query was 1;  
 
**select * from magento.core_config_data where path ='advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_Review'**.  
  
  Once I flipped the value to 0 and flushed the cache, the review tab showed up for our products.

Comment: in backend we have `Mage_Review` module enabled under `system>configuration>Advanced>Advanced`. is i need to disable it ?